# Can I change the body of a widget using setState?

Tags: flutter, dart

My application has scaffold.

But I want to change only the body of scaffold.

Normally I use `setState()` to change the state, but in this case, How can I use `setState()` or I can do some other way??

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

  void onTapped() {
    print ("tapped");
    // I want to change only body of Scaffold like this
    // body: new Text("new body");
  };
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: 
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => onTapped(),
        child:Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, whitebear! I changed your question title a bit in a way I think would make it more searchable by other people and generic, since it works for any child of any widgets? Hope you like it as well, best regards!

Comment: Hey @George, I think you need to fix your edit of the title of the question. I don't think "Change I change.." is what you wanted to put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just setState within the body of the scaffold, make the body a stateful widget and call setState within that widget. You can define your own stateless and stateful widgets by extending StatelessWidget or StatefulWidget. It is useful to define a particular thing as its own widget instead of just as a method that returns a widget because of how Flutter compartmentalizes the rebuilding process. If the body of the scaffold is its own widget, only that widget will be rebuilt when you call setState. If you do what the other answer suggests, you will rebuild MyHomePage, which includes the scaffold. On the other hand, if you define a stateful widget with a smaller scope, and then call setState() within that widget, only the widget with the smaller scope will be rebuilt.

For example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print('scaffold rebuilt');

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: ScaffoldBody(),
    );
  }
}

class ScaffoldBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScaffoldBodyState createState() => _ScaffoldBodyState();
}

class _ScaffoldBodyState extends State<ScaffoldBody> {

  int timesTapped = 0;

  void onTapped() {
    setState(() {
      timesTapped++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print('scaffold body rebuilt');

    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: onTapped,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times: $timesTapped',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, I understand. Making another scaffold class is the better idea for this case. thank you very much for great explanation.

Comment: This option really is better, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable `Widget _scaffoldBody;` to hold the current Scaffold body.

You set an initial value to it, and then call `setState` when you need to change the body.

Something like this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Widget _scaffoldBody;

  @override
  void initState(){
    // Initialize it with the first body you want visible.
    _scaffoldBody = GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => onTapped(),
      child:Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Note: move the onTapped method inside the state so you can call setState;
  void onTapped()
    // Call setState changing the body
    setState((){
      _scaffoldBody = Text("new body");
    });
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _scaffoldBody,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it also helpful and great answer